# How to set rows limit on a vert.x select query

Tags: vert.x

I'm using vert.x Database client and looking for a way to limit the number of rows of a SELECT query, without using SQL-extension-specific clause (such as TOP 10). The option that comes to mind is something like `java.sql.PreparedStatement.setMaxRows()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option on the Vert.x JDBC client.

Instead, update the SQL query to limit the number or rows return.